# How do I use mpg123 to extract the audio from a .mov video to a .wav file?

Tags: audio, video

I have some video files in .MOV format and I want to extract the audio from them to .WAV files. I cannot use MP3 files as I'm trying to feed the sound into a sonographic analysis program (WASP) that takes WAV files and only WAV files.
I'm sure I've done this before using mpg123, but I haven't done it for a while.
When I tried the command

```
mpg123 -w '2Jun2019 Dawn Chorus 1.wav' MVI_1145.MOV
```

I got this:

```
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.22.4; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes

Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: MVI_1145.MOV ...

MPEG 1.0 layer I, 11 kbit/s (free format), 44100 Hz stereo

[layer1.c:30] error: Illegal bit allocation value.

[layer1.c:171] error: Aborting layer I decoding after step one.


[layer1.c:30] error: Illegal bit allocation value.

[layer1.c:171] error: Aborting layer I decoding after step one.


[layer1.c:30] error: Illegal bit allocation value.

[layer1.c:171] error: Aborting layer I decoding after step one.

Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x00000000 at offset 1330.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 1024 bytes in input.

[parse.c:1249] error: Giving up resync after 1024 bytes - your stream is not nice... (maybe increasing resync limit could help).

[mpg123.c:695] error: ...in decoding next frame: Failed to find valid MPEG data within limit on resync. (code 28)

[0:00] Decoding of MVI_1145.MOV finished.
```

and a 6.2 kb file titled `2Jun2019 Dawn Chorus 1.wav` with nothing in it - when I tried to play it it came up in the player as 00 seconds long.

Please can somebody tell me what's the matter with the thing?  Somebody in the chat suggested I should say what the encoding is, but I'm afraid I don't know the answer; it's not in Properties and I don't know how else to find out.

Edit:  @Hermann asked what happened if I typed `ffprobe MVI_1145.MOV`.  Here's the result, as it's much too long to put in a comment.

```
    ffprobe version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MVI_1145.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2019-06-02 02:56:02
  Duration: 00:00:31.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15023 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720, 13140 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-02 02:56:02
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-02 02:56:02
```

Comment: See Hermann's answer. You can also convert the wav to mp3 with `lame -h -b 320 "file.wav" "file.mp3"`. Ffmpeg also has the capability to convert to other video formats, if that's what you want. Note that conversions can reduce the quality from source in certain cases.

Comment: MP3 won't do, unfortunately, as I'm trying to feed the sound into a sonographic analysis program (WASP) that takes WAV files and only WAV files.  (Shabby of it, but it's free so what can you expect?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mpg123](http://mpg123.de/features.shtml) handles audio from "MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layer I/II/III" sources. QuickTime MOV is closer to MPEG-4 (which is not explicitly supported by mpg123).

How about using ffmpeg instead?

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_1145.MOV -vn '2Jun2019 Dawn Chorus 1.wav'
```

`-vn` explicitly disables video. Output format is automagically detected based on filename extension.

Update: Since the input's audio stream already is uncompressed PCM, you can request a direct stream copy with `-c:a copy` (it sets the output **a**udio en**c**oder to "copy input"):

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_1145.MOV -c:a copy -vn '2Jun2019 Dawn Chorus 1.wav'
```

Comment: OK, I've now tried that, and this time got a WAV file containing 31 seconds of dead silence.  Thanks for the attempt.  Any idea what THAT one's about?

Comment: @A.B. What does `ffprobe MVI_1145.MOV` yield?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how best to tell you since it's far too long for a comment; I've posted it as an answer - if there's a better idea, do edit, anyone.

Comment: Actually I've bodged it onto the main question, since I thought of a way of doing that that more or less made sense.

Comment: @A.B. according to `ffprobe`, your input is only 31 seconds long. I am fairly confident that `ffmpeg` does the conversion to wav properly. You can try `-c:a copy` to request a non-converting extraction. Are you sure the input is not filled with silence? Are you maybe willing to share your input file?

Comment: That technique worked for me on a MOV file (originally from an old Kodak digital camera) with pcm_s16le audio.

Comment: @Hermann Egg on face.  I hadn't tested it and it turns out the file was, indeed, a dud!  Nothing on the soundtrack but occasional very faint background noises.  (Even those weren't audible until I turned it up to max volume, or I'd have realised sooner that it wasn't a software fault.)  Must have been strange acoustics; the birdsong I was recording was very audible through the window to the naked ear, much louder than the background noises, but apparently the camera couldn't hear it at all!

Comment: Well, that means the original problem is solved and I'll be able to convert the rest of my videos - I tested another one with your ffmpeg command and it worked.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try:

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.wav -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -b:a 1536k output.wav
```

Comment: @0xSheepdog the "what happens if you try" phrasing isn't the best; it does appear to be an attempt to answer the question. user2752471, if you're *actually* unsure of your answer, it'd be better to (gain a few reputation points and then) post a comment to see what the results are. Otherwise, if you think you have an answer, you might avoid "questioning" phrases like "Try this" or "What happens if".

Comment: Answering the question, so the poster or whoever else can edit it if necessary:  You meant `ffmpeg -i your_file.MOV -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -b:a 1536k output.wav` - I realised when I tried to fill it in that you'd put "wav" instead of "MOV".  Easily done.  With that alteration, yes, that works too, well done.

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller. Thanks for the suggestions. I was sure that it worked with files that I have here, but unsure about his file. Anyway, I did not know when to use one and when to use the other. However, I did try to comment first, only to realize that I cannot do so because I do not have 50 of reputation.